# RAML: using same data type for GET & POST with differing properties

Tags: jsonschema, raml

So I'm extracting a JSON schema out of my RAML spec to validate output in GET methods and also the input in the POST method.

Every entity of this type has a "required" ID property - at least it's required when listing those entities in a 'get item' or 'get collection'-request.
But when validating the received post data to create such an entity the ID is obviously not required (and discarded if it's send anyway).

What's the best DRY way to have this ID property required for GET requests, but not required, or even better not existing in the type for POST requests?

**TL;DR:** start reading below ;)

Example to make it easier to understand:

For GET requests the type should be like:

```
properties:
  id:
  something1: 
  something2?:
```

For POST requests the type should be like:

```
properties:
  something1: 
  something2?:
```

without having to define both separately, but also without using inheritance to have to create two types for every resource.

Ideally I would solve it that way, but that doesn't seem to work:

```
get:
  description: Retrieve a list of <<resourcePathName|!uppercamelcase>>.
  responses:
    200:
      body:
        application/json:
          type: [ entity_id_object, <<resourcePathName|!singularize|!uppercamelcase>> ][]
          example: <<exampleCollection>>
```

and `entity_id_object` ist just:

```
entity_id_object:
   properties:
     id:
```

I think it's because the `<<resourcePathName|!singularize|!uppercamelcase>>` is not working in this combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a way of doing it without two types yet. But this example at least only makes you only pass one type and automatically appends 'NoId' to the type name for POST requests.

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: My API
version: v1
mediaType: application/json

types:
  ResponseNoId:
    properties:
      something1: 
      something2?:
  ResponseId:
    properties:
      id:
      something1: 
      something2?:
  Response:
    ResponseNoId|ResponseId

resourceTypes:
  collection:
    usage: Use this resourceType to represent a collection of items
    description: A collection of <<resourcePathName|!uppercamelcase>>
    get:
      description: |
        Get all <<resourcePathName|!uppercamelcase>>,
        optionally filtered
      is: [ hasResponseCollection: { typeName: <<typeName>> } ]
    post:
      description: |
        Create a new <<resourcePathName|!uppercamelcase|!singularize>>
      is: [ hasRequestItem: { typeName: <<typeName>> } ]
  item:
    usage: Use this resourceType to represent any single item
    description: A single <<typeName>>
    get:
      description: Get a <<typeName>>
      is: [ hasResponseItem: { typeName: <<typeName>> } ]

traits:
  hasRequestItem:
    body:
      application/json:
        type: <<typeName>>
  hasResponseItem:
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            type: <<typeName>>
  hasResponseCollection:
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            type: <<typeName>>[]

/myResource:
  type: { collection: { typeName: Response } }
  get:

  /{id}:
    type: { item: { typeName: Response } }
  post:
    body:
      application/json:
```

Comment: I think you're probably right that this is generally the least bad way to do it ;) But `ResponseId` could just inherit from `ResponseNoId` and then only have `id` as an additional property, right? As a suggested improvement to your answer

Comment: exactly you could use inheritance if you want to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the `id` field as [`readOnly`](https://json-schema.org/draft-07/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.10.3) to make the intent clear, although it won't have an effect on the way that the data is validated.

To affect validation, you can create a "Read" type and a "Write" type, where the "Read" type has the extra required `id` property.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "MyWriteEntity": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "something1": { "type": "string"},
        "something2": { "type": "string"}
      },
      "required": "something1"
    },
    "MyReadEntity": {
      "allOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/MyWriteEntity" },
        {
          "id": { "type": "string", "readOnly": true},
          "required": ["id"]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is of course a solution. The thing is I would have to do this for a lot of types - because it's the same problem everywhere, they all got an ID property which should be in the output but not in the input. So no way around using two types (with inheritance) for each resource?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to create a RAML Library fragment, lets say "foo.raml" for a data model "foo" for resources /foos and /foos/{fooID}.

In the library, create three types:
fooInput:
properties:
something1:
something2:
fooOutput:
type: fooInput
properties:
id: integer
fooPatch:
properties:
something1?:
something2?:

Now in ONE file you have 3 data types. Use the Input version with PUT/POST, use the Output version for GET and use the Patch version for PATCH endpoints.  This is even better when paired with resourceTypes.